# SQL / LINQ to SQL translation verification

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Would someone be kind enough to tell me if I have this translated correctly.  Here is my SQL:

```
CASE WHEN p.prioid IN ('1 - Routine', '6 - Planned Outage') THEN 'Planned' ELSE 'Unplanned' END as Planning
```

Here is my Ling to SQL:

```
List <string> routines = new List<string>();
routines.Add("1 - Routine");
routines.Add("6 - Planned Outage");

Planning = routines.Contains(pri.Prioid) ? "Planned" : "UnPlanned";
```

Comment: No, you changed the case of `'Unplanned'` :D.  But seriously, the code is equivalent.  BTW, nothing about this uses LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @ Jeff Mercado : Thank you for your help.  So this has nothing to do with LINQ to SQL?  I'm doing a programming internship and they told me I was translating SQL into LINQ to SQL (using LINQPad) and then putting that code into Visual Studio, where I have to tweak it "for it to work in C#".  Since I've never even heard of LINQ or LINQ to SQL until last week, I took their work for it and kept my mouth shut. So can I assume that I am translating SQL into C#?  That would make sense and clear up a lot of questions/confusion I had.

Comment: Yes, it's actually just regular C# code.  If you had written an actual query (e.g., `from row in table select row`), then that probably would have involved LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @ Jeff Mercado - Thanks you for clearing that up.